# Excel VBA Popup Whenever A Particular Text Appear In A Column

Tags: excel, vba, popup

I'm handling an Excel with some stock prices data updating on real-time basis (.rtd function) linked to a trading software. Trying to get a popup alert whenever a condition is matched and text "Buy" and "Sell" appear in column "G" only.

Puzzled with this following code but popup is appearing only when the data is changed manually. Nothing appears when data updates dynamically.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Range("G3:G550").Find(what:="Sell", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True) Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Sell" & Target.Address
Else
MsgBox "Buy" & Target.Address
End If
End Sub
```

Tried This But Nothing Happened.... Can You Help Me With This...???

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() 

    Dim Rng1 As Range 
    Dim Value As String 
    Dim Prompt As String 
    Dim Title As String 

    Set Rng1 = Range("G3:G500") 
    Value = Buy 
    Prompt = "Buy This" 
    Title = "Name" 

    If Rng1.Value = Value Then 
        MsgBox Prompt, vbInformation, Title 
    End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` is not triggered by a formula calculation.  You'd need `worksheet_calculate` for that.

Comment: Maybe try: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/549506-rtd-value-changes-not-triggering-worksheet-change-event.html

Comment: I don't have access to any RDT to test.

Comment: You **MUST NOT** Capitalize Each And Every Single Word In English!!